# How can I override or bubble up javascript try/catch blocks

Tags: javascript

I have an application that uses a few external libraries. These libraries use try/catch blocks to deal with errors. Rather then editing the libraries and removing the try/catch blocks is there a way to force them to bubble up to a function I control so that I can post them to my server?

here is an example

```
'parseBindingsString': function(bindingsString, bindingContext, node, options) {
        try {
            var bindingFunction = createBindingsStringEvaluatorViaCache(bindingsString, this.bindingCache, options);
            return bindingFunction(bindingContext, node);
        } catch (ex) {
            ex.message = "Unable to parse bindings.\nBindings value: " + bindingsString + "\nMessage: " + ex.message;
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that external libraries are handling exceptions that you generated manually?

Comment: No. What exactly do those libraries do in the `catch` blocks? It would be nice if you could post an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. If an Exception is thrown and catched, it won't bubble up again (unless the `catch` blocks rethrows the exception).

Comment: and in the case of the throw in the catch block above?

Comment: @HaydenChambers: That should bubble up. If it doesn't, there's another `catch` block between your code and the exception.